# js 'toggle' or 'hover' function?

Tags: javascript, css, hover, toggle

I don't want to use the `toggle`, what would I need to use to get the following `nav` structure to stay put when main link is hovered over?

Current js:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".downservices").hover(function(){
      $(".servicesdropped").toggle("fast");
    });
  });
</script>
```

[Sample page](http://musclefire.com/nav2.php)

(Notice that when the submenu pops up, I cannot click on the links, as the submenu fades away)

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't fussed about animation, and you wish to use JQuery you can toggle the CSS visibility rule on the class.

```
$(document).ready(function()

// Make sure the item is hidden initially, best to do
// this in CSS.
$(".servicesdropped").css("visibility", "hidden");

{
    $(".downservices").hover(function()
    {
        $(".servicesdropped").css("visibility", "display");
    },
    function()
    {
        $(".servicesdropped").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
});
```

Using visiblity means the element will still consume the space it does in the DOM but does not display making sure the structure and positioning of other elements surrounding it are left in tact. The downside is that animations such as `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".downservices").hover(function(){
$(".servicesdropped").slideDown();
});
});
</script>
```

for hover out the menu disappear use this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".downservices").hover(
function(){
$(".servicesdropped").slideDown();
},
function(){
$(".servicesdropped").slideUp();
}
);
});
</script>
```

Comment: should be slideDown() (with lower 's')

Answer (score 0):

Your html markup architecture of menu should like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="downservices"><a href="#">GUYS</a>
    <div class="servicesdropped" style="display: none;">
      <ul class="middle">
        <h3>Shirts &amp; Tanks:</h3>
        <li><a href="#">MuSkull</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bamboo Athletic Tank</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Thin Strap Tank</a></li>
     </ul>

     <ul class="right">
       <h3>Other Stuff:</h3>
       <li><a href="#">Shorties</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Hoodies</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Socks</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in the script use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("li.downservices").hover(function()
   {
      $(this).find(".servicesdropped").slideDown("fast");
   },
   function()
   {
      $(this).find(".servicesdropped").slideUp("fast");
   });
});
```